# Disable submit button if dijit.form.DateTextBox is invalid

Tags: javascript, dojo

```
    When the user types the input in the dojotype="dijit.form.DateTextBox" as "Abcd" its shows the value entered is not valid.but its allowing the user to submit the form without any issues.
    I wanna disable the submit button if invalidmessage attribute of datetextbox shown up.
```

I m trying to implement the  function using the below code; Still i m not able to acheive  the functionality datatextbox.on is not triggering.I m new to dojo.Kindly help me on this.

```
function validateSubmit(){  
        alert('validate');
        var dateTextBox = dijit.byId("fromDedDate").get('value');
        alert('dateTextBox value '+dateTextBox);
        var dateTextBoxId = dijit.byId("fromDedDate");
        alert('dateTextBox id '+dateTextBoxId);
        var submitButton = document.getElementById('search');
        alert('submitButton '+submitButton);
        dateTextBox.on('change', function(e){
        var result = dateTextBox.validate();
        alert('result');
        });
}

    <form:input
                    path="deductionSearchFilter.deductionDateFrom" size='20'
                    id="fromDedDate" dojotype="dijit.form.DateTextBox"
                    onchange="dijit.byId('toDedDate').constraints.min = arguments[0];"
                    size="10" style="width: 114"
                    title="A single Deduction Date can be entered in the From/To fields or a range of Deduction Dates can be entered to search multiple days." />
    <td align='center'><input id="search" onclick="validateSubmit();" type="submit" name="Search"
                    value="Search" class="button" 
                    title="View the results of search" />
                </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could connect to the change event from your dateTextBox and hook up a handler. You should note that this won't prevent the form from submitting when a user presses enter.

```
var dateTextBox = registry.byId('dateTextBox');
var submitButton = registry.byId('submitButton');
dateTextBox.on('change', function(e){
  var result = dateTextBox.validate();
  submitButton.set('disabled', result);
});
```

If you want more control over your forms i would recommend wrapping your form element in a dijit/form/Form. Check the reference: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/form/Form.html for examples.

Comment: @Varsha Again: This is not the way to go on Stackoverflow. Better than saying just thankyou is accepting the answer and upvoting it. Just wanted to add that it looks like you are using an old dojo version. For example "dojotype" should be "data-dojo-type"  and btw: When you write your own widgets (later) you can use data-dojo-attach-point="submitButton" in your templates and then registry.byId('submitButton') would be this.submitButton ...

Comment: Thanks for your help.I dono how to connect the dateTextBox.on('change', function(e){} with the dojotype="dijit.form.DateTextBox".Whatever i m trying its not working.Any help will be appreciated.